# Android Kotlin - Problems implementing Google Credential Manager

Tags: android, kotlin, google-signin

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_login)

    gooLog()  
}


@Composable
fun gooLog(){

    val credentialManager = CredentialManager.create(this)
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    val googleIdOption: GetGoogleIdOption = GetGoogleIdOption.Builder()
        .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
        .setServerClientId("blajo")
        .build()

    val request: GetCredentialRequest = GetCredentialRequest.Builder()
        .addCredentialOption(googleIdOption)
        .build()

    coroutineScope.launch {
        try {
            val result = credentialManager.getCredential(
                request = request,
                context = this@GoogleLogin,
            )
            handleSignIn(result)
        } catch (e: GetCredentialException) { Log.d("pikaboo", "I love google")}
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make the login process start as soon as the activity opens.

This way I get those errors:

```
@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function
```

at: `gooLog()` inside `Oncreate`

and

```
Calls to launch should happen inside a LaunchedEffect and not composition
```

at `lunch` in `coroutineScope.launch`

---

when I remove `@Composable` then those errors disappear but I get

```
Functions which invoke @Composable functions must be marked with the @Composable annotation
```

at `fun gooLog()`

and

```
@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function
```

at `rememberCoroutineScope()`

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing XML layouts with Jetpack Compose in a way that is not supported.
You have to decide to use *either* `setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_login)` to use your XML layout *or* `setContent { gooLog() }` to use Compose.

The first approach, however, doesn't provide a composable context so you can't use `gooLog()`, the second approach on the other hand expects your layout to be defined in `@Composable` functions so you can't inflate `R.layout.activity_google_login` into a View.

Although there exists an [Interoperability API](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/migrate/interoperability-apis) that allows you to combine both approaches, it looks like you actually do not need Compose at all. Have a look at the question [Credential Manager - How do I create a "SignInWithGoogle" credential?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77627128/credential-manager-how-do-i-create-a-signinwithgoogle-credential) to get an idea how to set this up without using Compose.

Comment: The answer is using JAVA, when I convert it to Kotlin I still face all kind of bs