Refresh token for Google Sign In with Credential Manager
Is there a way to silently refresh tokens with the new Google Sign-In (Credential Manager)?
The legacy Google Sign-In had a silentSignIn method, which the Credential Manager lacks. How can I refresh the token without prompting the account selection again?
I've set setAutoSelectEnabled(true) in getCredential, but it still shows a sign-in prompt. I want to refresh the token exactly like the previous silentSignIn.

no such feature available right now. pls go through comments of
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77643555/8112590
